# Is there any way to export a function from a class component?

Tags: reactjs

```
class Options extends Component {
  
const indexHandler = (index) => {
      const { userAnswer, answer, score } = this.state;
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: index,
      });
    };

render(){
return(){
  
   }
 }  
}

export {
  
  indexHandler,
  
  
};
```

here I am unable to export this function!
but if the same function is declared outside the class component, the function can be exported!
Any help regarding this would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two thing i need to explain.

1. you’re trying to pass state, functions in the wrong way.
2. classes won't work differently in React, JS also. **a class is just a blueprint for an object. The class create an instance of an object:**

   ```
   export {

   indexHandler,


   };
   ```

export is done outside the class. So this won't pass the function you referenced in the Option Class.

**You can't export things inside functions or classes in javascript.**

to get the access for `indexHandler` method you need to pass `indexHandler` as a prop from `Option` component to use `indexHandler` for its descendants.

For example

```
class Options extends Component {

indexHandler = (index) => {
const { userAnswer, answer, score } = this.state; // Search Component will pass the state of it via 'changeIndex' and can change the state we need here.
this.setState({
  currentIndex: index,
});
};

render() {
return <Search changeIndex={this.indexHandler.bind(this)} />;
  }

}
```